# How does O-benzoyl-N-methylhydroxylamine hydrochloride oxidise this ketone?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, redox, carbonyl-compounds

[image: Reaction shown]

How does the mechanism of this reaction with BzONHMe work? Can part of it act as a base and abstract the alpha proton? Would be great if someone could help me!

Comment: This can't act as a base. It is a hydrochloride salt.

Answer (score 6):

The first step is the formation of the Me,O-Bz imine of the ketone. This tautomerises to the enamine which then does a pericyclic rearrangement with the carbonyl of the benzoyl group to install O at the alpha position. Finally  the imine hydrolyses to reveal the ketone. See [Aldrich Chemfiles (2007) 7.1](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/content/dam/sigma-aldrich/docs/Aldrich/Brochure/al_chemfile_v7_n1.pdf), page 7.

[image: Abridged mechanism]

Comment: So the HCl doesn't really do anything? Can't it protonate the ketone and then the alpha-proton gets abstracted by the amine resulting in a positive charge on the amine, letting the neighbouring oxygen get taken by the double bond between carbonyl carbon and alpha-carbon?

Comment: Remember that the substrate you are reacting with has a basic centre which is more basic than the benzoylhydroxylamine

Comment: Thank you very much! I figured it out now, your mechanism makes a lot of sense!

Comment: @ClaraMarie If an answer has helped you, it's a good idea to upvote and/or accept it (green tick next to voting buttons). Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) for further details.